# How do I change the editor used by visudo?

Tags: raspbian, setup

I would really like it to be vi or vim.  I mistakenly typed some vi commands in the default editor for visudo, which I believe is nano, and  broke /etc/sudoers so badly I think I am going to have to burn a new image and start over.

I've been able to run visudo again by doing  pkexec bash but I broke something in the default line entry and I haven't been able to repair it correctly and sudo won't run.

Comment: Side note: `mcedit` is a nice alternative if you don't actually want to remember vim/nano/emacs shortcuts

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can set the system editor by calling as root:

```
update-alternatives --set editor /usr/bin/vim.tiny
```

You have to install vim first.

This will change the editor globally, not just for visudo.

Comment: For a handy TUI to select from a list, run `update-alternatives --config editor`

Answer (score 10):

If you want to change this only temporarily, run

```
EDITOR=vim visudo
```

as root (else `sudo EDITOR=vim visudo`). To make `vim` the default editor for `visudo` but nothing else, you can put

```
alias visudo='EDITOR=vim visudo'
```

into your `~/.alias` or `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: `EDITOR=vim sudo visudo` does not work as expected since sudo by default drops all env variables for security reasons. (I was simply trying out the commands).

Comment: @mirk My bad, `sudo` belongs in front of the whole line